# Can't get item quantity to show in initial value of form

Tags: django, python-2.7

I'm making an online store. In the cart (views.show_cart) view which currently shows the 'Product', 'Unit Price', 'Quantity', 'Total Price', then the form which allows you to update the Quantity, and the 'Update' Button for each product in the cart.

I'd like the initial value of the form to match the 'Quantity' for each item (product) already in the Cart. However, I cant get this to work. I tried a for loop through the cart_items (in views.show_cart) to grab the item.quantity, then added this as the initial value in the form but each item's quantity shows the quantity of the last item. In other words, there are 2 items in cart, one with quantity of 3, and the other with quantity of 7. Both items form are showing a 7.

```
#the form
PRODUCT_QUANTITY_CHOICES = [(i, str(i)) for i in range(1, 21)]
class ProductAddToCartForm(forms.Form):
    quantity = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=PRODUCT_QUANTITY_CHOICES, coerce=int)
    update = forms.BooleanField(required=False,initial=False,widget=forms.HiddenInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

#cart view (cart_id.views.show_cart)
def show_cart(request):
    cart_id = _cart_id(request)
    cart_items = CartItem.objects.filter(cart_id=cart_id)
    for item in cart_items:
        q = item.quantity
        print q    #prints to shell w/correct quantities.
    add_product_form = ProductAddToCartForm(initial={'quantity': q})
    context = {'cart_items': cart_items, 'add_product_form': add_product_form}
```

Here's the other view involved (cart_id.views.cart_add)

```
def cart_add(request, product_slug):
    cart_id = _cart_id(request)
    p = get_object_or_404(Product, slug=product_slug)
    cart_products = CartItem.objects.filter(cart_id=cart_id)
    product_in_cart = False
    if request.method == 'POST':        
        form = ProductAddToCartForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            quantity = cd['quantity']
            update = cd['update']
            for cart_item in cart_products:
                if cart_item.product.id == p.id:
                    cart_item.quantity = quantity    
                    cart_item.save()
                    product_in_cart = True
            if not product_in_cart:
                ci = CartItem()
                ci.product = p
                ci.quantity += quantity    
                ci.cart_id = cart_id
                ci.save()        
            return redirect('cart:show_cart')
```

The Template (cart.html)

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
    {% load staticfiles %}

    {% block title %}Shopping Cart{% endblock %}
    {% block content %} {% endblock %}
    {% block extra_content %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-12">

        h2>Cart</h2>
    <caption><b>Your Shopping Cart:</b> {{ cart_items_count }} Items In Your Cart.</caption>    
    <hr>

        {% for item in cart_items %}
        <table class="table table-striped">
             <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th>Unit Price</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Total Price</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

             <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="{{ item.product.get_absolute_url }}">{{ item.product }}</a></td>
                    <td>${{ item.product.price }}</td> 
                    <td>{{ item.quantity }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.total }}</td>
                    <td>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <form action="{% url 'cart:add' item.product.slug %}" method="POST">                                
                                {% csrf_token %}
                            <div class="col-xs-3">
                                {{ add_product_form.quantity }}
                            </div>                                
                                {{ add_product_form.update }}                                                                
                            <input class='btn btn-success btn-sm' type='submit' value='Update'/>                                
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            {% empty %}
            <h3>You Have Nothing In Your Cart.</h3>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>    
{% endblock %}
```

The model:

```
class CartItem(models.Model):
    cart_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_index=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
```

Here's the entire code on github if needed: https://github.com/chriskavanagh/ecommerce/tree/master/src. .I apologize for the bad spacing in this post.

Comment: `add_product_form = ProductAddToCartForm(initial={'q': q})`: shouldn't this be: `add_product_form = ProductAddToCartForm(initial={'quantity': q})` since the form field's name is `'quantity'`?

Comment: Yes thanks, however it then shows the value of the last item in all the forms, instead of each items value (quantity). In other words, there are 2 items in the cart now, one with a quantity of 3, and one with a quantity of 7. But, each items form shows a 7.

Comment: That's because you pass only one form in the template context, but render this one instance for each item. You gotta instantiate one form instance for each item and pass all of them to the template.

Comment: So, indent the line `add_product_form = ProductAddToCartForm(initial={'quantity': q})` under the for loop? If this what you mean, I tried this and got the same result. . . Or am I not doing it correctly? (and thanks for the help!)

Comment: Once I indented the add_product_form into the for loop, the form prints to the shell correctly, with the correct initial values. . .However it still doesn't show correctly when I view the actual page. . .So, I'm guessing the problem is in the template. Any ideas?